# Удалить подгружающийся элементы родителя

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<select name="selectt" id="select" class="data_field">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Я могу получить элементы `option` через js

```
select_prod.querySelectorAll('select>option');
```

Но вопрос - как их потом удалить? Цикл не совсем подходит потому что при выборе предыдущего селекта сюда грузится дополнительно еще опции.

Comment: `document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = "";`

Comment: пардон, все элементы В `select`е (option)

Comment: цикл подходит, просто вы выбираете _все_ элементы option на странице, а не только из конкретного select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var count = 4; //число элемента по счету
var option = select.childNodes[count * 2];
var option2 = select.childNodes[count * 2 - 1];
option.remove();
option2.remove();
```

Comment: Ну и что это? И зачем?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = "";
```